# nuxeo check if directory exists through API

Tags: javascript, nuxeo, nuxeo-js-client

Let's say I have a directory at

```
/foo/bar/bazz
```

Let's say I would like to verify its existence programmatically:

```
client = new nuxeo.Client(nuxeoParams)
client.connect()
fetchOp = client.operation "Diretory.Entries"
path = "doc:/foo/bar/bazz"
fetchParams = directoryName: path
fetchOp.params(fetchParams)
fetchOp.execute(function(error, data){
    if(error){
      console.debug('error')
    } else {
      console.debug('data')
    }
})
```

This show a 404 error. Why? What am I missing? How do I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> `fetchOp = client.operation "Diretory.Entries"`

Did you misspell `fetchOp = client.operation "Directory.Entries"`?